# Query with whereHas and sum of relationship column

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I have a query for adding custom "balance" column using sum of values in relation table.

```
User::withCount(['transactions as balance' => function($query) {
     $query->select(\DB::raw('sum(credit_movement)'));
}]);
```

This works fine for returning "balance" column.

---

Now, I want to filter the users regarding the "balance" column.

`->where('balance', '<', 0);`

If I chain it to the query, it won't work as "balance" column does not exist.

```
User::withCount(['transactions as balance' => function($query) {
     $query->select(\DB::raw('sum(credit_movement)'));
}])
->where('balance', '<', 0);
```

---

I tried using

```
User::withCount(['transactions as balance' => function($query) {
     $query->select(\DB::raw('sum(credit_movement)'));
}])
->having('balance', '<', 0); // won't work

// also:
->havingRaw('balance < 0'); // won't work
```

But none of these works.

> Unknown column 'balance' in 'having clause'

I want the query to return only the users which have balances less than 0. (and I want to achieve it in query builder, not `->filter()` on the collection.

---

**Update:**

I tried using `whereHas()` but couldn't write it properly

```
User::withCount(['transactions as balance' => function($query) {
     $query->select(\DB::raw('sum(credit_movement)'));
}])
   ->whereHas('transactions', function($q) {
      $q->whereRaw('sum(credit_movement), < ?', 0);
   });
```

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' < ?)

Comment: try `balance_count` instead of `balance`

Comment: `withCount` counts models which are returned from the select. It does not do a group by so you can't use `having`. You can try doing `whereHas` and within the function do a  groupBy/having. Not tried it though so not sure if it will work.

Comment: I tried doing with `whereHas()` but couldn't write the where query using sum. `->where('sum(credit_movement)', '<', 0)` or `->whereRaw('sum(credit_movement) < ?, 0)`. Do you guys have any ideas on that?

Comment: `->whereRaw('sum(credit_movement) <= 0')` will this help?

Comment: @dqureshiumar It returns `General error: 1111 Invalid use of group function`

Comment: you can try `->havingRaw('sum(credit_movement) < 0')` or `->having(sum(credit_movement),'<',0)`

Comment: `->having('sum(credit_movement) <= 0')` returns _"Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sum(credit_movement) <= 0' in 'having clause'"_. `->havingRaw('sum(credit_movement) <= 0')` returns _"Syntax error or access violation: 1140 In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'my_store.transactions.id'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by"_

Comment: `->havingRaw('SUM(credit_movement) < ? ' , [0])` please try this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222199/discussion-between-dqureshiumar-and-senty).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally got it working:

```
User::whereHas('transactions', function($q) {
   $q->select(\DB::raw('SUM(credit_movement) as balance'))
       ->havingRaw('balance < 0');
   });
});
```